# Carbon diffForHumans() not working on datetime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

my home tab(All) just works perfectly fine, but when i go to the 2nd tab which is div load content, the diffForHumans() will no longer work. this is the code from my model:

```
 protected $dates = ['schedule'];
```

and this is from my home.blade.php:

```
<div class="time">
                        @if($match->status == 'ongoing')
                        <span style="color: #72A326; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #4A7010; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">&nbsp;LIVE</span>
                        @elseif($match->status == 'settled')
                        {{$match->schedule->diffForHumans()}} <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">&nbsp;SETTLED</span>
                        @elseif($match->status == 'draw')
                        {{$match->schedule->diffForHumans()}} <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">&nbsp;DRAW - CREDITS RETURNED</span>
                        @else
                        <strong class="match_countdown" data-schedule="{{$match->schedule}}">{{$match->schedule->diffForHumans()}}</strong>
                        @endif
                    </div>
```

and this is from my dota.blade.php

```
<div class="time">
                    @if($match->status == 'ongoing')
                    <span style="color: #72A326; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #4A7010; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">&nbsp;LIVE</span>
                    @elseif($match->status == 'settled')
                    {{$match->schedule->diffForHumans()}} <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">&nbsp;SETTLED</span>
                    @elseif($match->status == 'draw')
                    {{$match->schedule->diffForHumans()}} <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">&nbsp;DRAW - CREDITS RETURNED</span>
                    @else
                    <strong class="match_countdown" data-schedule="{{$match->schedule}}">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($match->schedule)->diffForHumans() }}</strong>
                    @endif
                </div>
```

and this is the script:

```
  <script>    
$(function(){
    var now = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    var to_tournament_date = moment("2017-08-03T00:00:00+08:00").fromNow();
    $('.tournament-winner-timer').html(to_tournament_date);
})
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('.match_countdown'), function(key, index) {
        countdown(this, $(this).data('schedule'));
    });

    function countdown(element, time) {
        var countDownDate = parseInt(moment(time).format('x'));
        var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            element.innerHTML = (days > 0 ? days + "d " : "") + (hours > 0 ? hours + "h " : "") + (minutes > 0 ? minutes + "m " : "") + seconds + "s from now";

            // If the count down is finished, write some text 
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                element.innerHTML = "Match will start soon";
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

so basically, there's really no difference at all. from my home blade tab, it just works fine both have the same scripts as well, on my home it displays 3 days 2 hrs 46 secs from now, and when the schedule time reaches 0, it switches to status "Match will start soon" so now, on my dota tab it doesn't work the same way. any ideas why?